# JavaFX Fire TextField ActionEvent manually | programmatically

Tags: java, events, javafx

I know some ways avoiding that like adding the same ActionHandler in different nodes:

```
        // Custom Event Handler
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> myHandler = e -> {

             //code

        };

        inputField.setOnAction(myHandler);

        // okButton
        okButton.setOnAction(myHandler);
```

But i can see a method `fireEvent(Event)` inside the Node class.The problem is that i have multiple `TextFields` and when the `Button` named `okButton` is pressed i want to fire them all at once.

How that can be done ? If it not something that makes to you not much sense , say that i want it for research reasons :).

Comment: Instead of firing the event manually, make your button a default button by calling its [setDefaultButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#setDefaultButton-boolean-) method.

Comment: I have used `.fireEvent(new ActionEvent())` to fire my `TextField`s action handler. I did have to iterate through every `TextField` and call `fireEvent` on each one though. I haven't used a `Button` to do that before. I guess its the possibility of a start.

Comment: @MichaelPickett Youcan  add it as an answer :)

Comment: @VGR Can i have an example?

Comment: `okButton.setDefaultButton(true);`.  It really is that easy.

Comment: @VGR I don't think that's the question. That would fire the button if Enter is pressed, not fire the text fields if the button were pressed.

Comment: @James_D It is interesting though.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested by OP, I am adding my comment as an answer.

You can use `.fireEvent(new ActionEvent())` to fire the `TextField`s action handler.

The way I have accomplished this was by storing/getting all of the `TextField`s, when then when a `Button` is pressed, iterate over every one and `.fireEvent(new ActionEvent());`. Small controller example below. VBox is from an FXML file.

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML private VBox root;
    private List<TextField> all = new ArrayList<>();

    public Controller(){}
    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        EventHandler<ActionEvent> customEvent = e -> {
            if(e.getSource().getClass() == Button.class){
                all.forEach(t -> t.fireEvent(new ActionEvent()));
            }else {
                System.out.println(((TextField) e.getSource()).getText());
            }
        };

        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
            TextField tf = new TextField(Integer.toString(i));
            tf.setOnAction(customEvent);
            all.add(tf);
            root.getChildren().add(tf);
        }
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setOnAction(customEvent);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see any valid reason for doing this: you're basically asking for a controller to invoke user events on the view, instead of doing what it normally does and update the model.

So I guess the closest thing I could come up with would be something like this. Suppose you had (using the canonical JavaFX example), a `Person` class:

```
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty() ;
    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty() ;

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName ;
    }

    public final String getFirstName() {
        return firstNameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
    }

    // etc etc
}
```

and then an editor of some kind. You can create a map in the editor mapping each text field to an action to perform, and then register a single event handler with each text field that invokes the corresponding action. Your button could iterate through the map and call all the actions:

```
public class PersonEditor {

     private TextField firstNameTextField ;
     private TextField lastNameTextField ;
     private TextField emailTextField ;

     private Button okButton ;


     public PersonEditor(Person person) {

         // create controls, do layout, etc etc...

         // map textfields to an action on the person:
         Map<TextField, Consumer<String>> actions = new HashMap<>();
         actions.put(firstNameTextField, person::setFirstName);             
         actions.put(lastNameTextField, person::setLastName);             
         actions.put(emailTextField, person::setEmail);

         // set individual event handlers on each text field:
         actions.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
             TextField tf = entry.getKey();
             tf.setOnAction(e -> entry.getValue().accept(tf.getText()));
         });

         // event handler for button:
         okButton.setOnAction(e -> {
             // invoke action on each text field:
             actions.entrySet().forEach(entry -> entry.getValue().accept(entry.getKey().getText()));
             // do other stuff if needed...
         }

    }

}
```